# Fancybox issue, on click open just img

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

Here is code in `head`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

code before `/body`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
overlay: {
  locked: false
}
}
    });
});
</script>
```

and code where used fancybox

```
<li><a href="img/img1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="group"><img src="img/img1.jpg" height="160" width="240" alt=""></a></li>
```

No errors in console, everything seems fine, but on click `a.fancybox` opens just image in same tab..
Here is [Site Url](http://testx1.bl.ee/), give an advice please :)

Where to click

[image]

Comment: Okay we got it! but what is your question?

Comment: why fancybox dont working?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hum .. You have all the code included .. I think it did not found the dom objects. For some reason when you work with bxslider and the fancybox plugin try to remove the bxslider to see if it remains the same problem.

It is not properly include javascript code sequence CroaToa has found it. It was the mouse wheel include  after fancybox.

Comment: Is the bxslider make ajax calls or something?

Comment: The answer you posted is a **comment** after all I voted it up, just helping out the little guy

Comment: Where you initialize the .fancybox object in document ready can you put one console.log($('.fancybox')); to see if it sees the objects

Comment: @GeorgePlamenovGeorgiev No ajax. Sorry, I dont know where put console.log, I'm new in js

Comment: Put it like this

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($(".fancybox"))
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});

Comment: @GeorgePlamenovGeorgiev Put it. You can see after refreshing url.

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot one ';' This is the code: $(document).ready(function() { console.log($(".fancybox")); $(".fancybox").fancybox(); });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68824/discussion-between-george-plamenov-georgiev-and-croatoa).